# How to create a Dictionary data structure in Java which has capability for search with partial keys like 'goog%'

Tags: java

I need a data structure which will be used to store a stash of words in it and when I need to do a look up I should be able to get all the words starting with a keyword which can be a partial string of any word.

So let's say there are Google and Goggle in the dictionary added so far. And now if I call on search method with parameter 'go' then it should give me both Google and Goggle. But if I search 'Gogg' it should only give Goggle. All in Java (>=1.8)

There are similar questions in Stack overflow that I have seen but I don't find a suitable answer for it. Just a perfect node structure and a search technique would be enough for the answer. No use of existing APIs please. But you could mention their name so that they can be looked upon for understanding the implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a default Map collection with Stream API.

So lets imagine you have a map:

```
Map<String, Object> = ...;
```

Now, using the Stream API, you can iterate through the map and filter existing keys(or values) and the collect results on a new map:

```
Map<String, Object> searchResult = map.stream()
  .filter((k,v) -> k.toLowerCase().startsWith("go"))
  .collect(Collectors.toMap);
```

Comment: That is not efficient for a large number of values.

Answer (score 1):

> No use of existing APIs please

Makes it sound like this a [homework problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions), in which case what have you exactly tried till now?

If you want to do a prefix based search over a large set of strings, a [Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) should help.

There is an implementaion of the [Patricia Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree) present in [Apache Commons-Collection](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-4.1/org/apache/commons/collections4/trie/PatriciaTrie.html).

```
        PatriciaTrie<String> patriciaTrie = new PatriciaTrie<>();
        patriciaTrie.put("Google", "Google");
        patriciaTrie.put("Goggle", "Goggle");
        patriciaTrie.put("Abcd", "Abcd");
        patriciaTrie.put("Abcdefgh", "Abcdefgh");

        System.out.println("Search Key : Go");
        patriciaTrie.prefixMap("Go").forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k));

        System.out.println("Search Key : Gog");
        patriciaTrie.prefixMap("Gog").forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k));

        System.out.println("Search Key : Ab");
        patriciaTrie.prefixMap("Ab").forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k));
```

gives the output

```
Search Key : Go
Goggle
Google
Search Key : Gog
Goggle
Search Key : Ab
Abcd
Abcdefgh
```

Comment: I have found a Trie implementation in Java in a YouTube video already. I could post the link but only if that is ok with the regulations of the site. Cheers.